# redirect url using jwplayer

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, jwplayer, jwplayer6

i was new user jwplayer. I have one ***real video link*** 
    http://domain.com/share/upload/test.mp4

to play video use jwplayer, i use function

```
jwplayer('player3').setup({
    file:"http://localhost:8080/video/test.mp4"
})
```

but i want redirect url file in jwplay into url

```
http://domain.com/share/upload/test.mp4
```

and I've been using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ http://domain.com/share/upload/$1 [L]
```

but i can't play video. I need one solution

Comment: You need to do it the other way around, and leave out the `http://domain.com`. So `RewriteRule ^share/upload/(.*)$ /video/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-directing the file, try this.

Change:

```
file:"http://localhost:8080/video/test.mp4"
```

To:

```
file:"http://localhost:8080/video/test.mp4",
type: "mp4"
```

Does that work?